# Rank of the smallest rank-reducing perturbation of a general matrix

Tags: matrices, operator-norms

Let $A$ be a general $m \times n$ matrix (not necessarily square, and not necessarily of full rank). Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm for $m \times n$ matrices that is induced from a norm for $m$ vectors and from another norm for $n$ vectors. (I am writing all this out to emphasize that the matrix norm may be a completely arbitrary induced norm, and is not necessarily a standard Holder norm.) Let $E$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of smallest norm such that $\mbox {rank} (A+E) < \mbox {rank} (A)$. Can $E$ always be chosen to have $\mbox {rank}(E)=1$?

Comment: The answer is "no". In fact, you ask the following. Given a matrix $A$ of rank $r+1$, is $B\in V_r$, a matrix in the variety $V_r$ of all matrices of rank $\le r$, one of the closest to $A$, necessarily of rank $1$ ? It is easy to create a counter-example, whatever (fixed) norm you use.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong: did not read attentionally your question. But the answer still "no", as there are many $A$ such that $E$ is unique and, moreover, it can be even non-degenerate (if I am not wrong again).